# Installed emacs by emacs-bootstrap, got cannot load error and buffer list not work

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, buffers, osx

Using Mac Pro macOS 10.13.1

iTerm2

Has two problems:

1. After installed emacs by [emacs-bootstrap](http://emacs-bootstrap.com), got this error when start it:

[image]

2. When try to open buffer list by `C-x C-b`, it shown this window at bottom but not buffer list on the other side:

[image]

I found this config in the `~/.emacs.d/elisp/base-extensions.el` file:

```
(use-package org-projectile
  :config
  (org-projectile-per-project)
  (setq org-projectile-per-project-filepath "todo.org"
    org-agenda-files (append org-agenda-files (org-projectile-todo-files))))
```

What's the problem?

---

## Edit

When use `GNU Emacs For Mac OS X`, also got same warning:

[image]

## Edit 2

Add run `emacs` screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Why have you told us that you installed Emacs by `emacs-bootstrap` and how does that fact have anything to do with the error message that you receive when playing with `use-package` and `org-projectile`?

Comment: @lawlist I don't know the reason why got that error and why can't open buffer list. So if anyone has the same issue, it will be helpful.

Comment: If you have any reason to suspect the build process, then just down-load a pre-built version from:  https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. I tried that, but got the same warning, too. I added the picture to the question. But use it the `C-x C-b` works!

Comment: How about giving us the settings you are using for `use-package` so that someone who is familiar with how to use that package can tell you what you did wrong?

Comment: @lawlist I grep `use-package` under `~/.emacs.d` path, no matches found. At least, it can be used now.

Comment: @lawlist I found that config about `org-projectile`! Added to the question.

Comment: @online, I'm a bit confused. `~/.emacs.d/elisp/base-extensions.el` is obviously something you've added, but from your question it all sounds a bit new to you. Is this your own config? Something you've used before? Something you've just downloaded? Something that `emacs-bootstrap` (whatever that is -- you've failed to provide any information) installed for you?

Comment: @phils I am new to emacs so use [emacs-bootstrap](http://emacs-bootstrap.com) is an easy way for me. But I don't know how to resolve the problem if it happens. I think it's a perfect one that can be used immediately without any manual config.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The Generate button doesn't do anything when I try it, so I can't test it out. You should perhaps mention which options you selected, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a dependency issue -- the `org-projectile` package requires `org-category-capture-0.0.0` which requires `org-9.0.0` which is not available. (Maybe because it's too old? org-mode.org says 9.1.6 is current, in any case.)

**Edit:** In fact version 9.1.6 is fine, so that must be a minimum version dependency.  In which case you will probably be missing the ELPA package archive for org-mode (as was I in my initial test).

https://orgmode.org/elpa.html says:

> Add this to your Emacs init file to be able to list the Org mode archives:
>
> ```
> (require 'package)
> (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
> ```

Failing that, you may just need to run `M-x package-refresh-contents`

This seems like a bug with the emacs-bootstrap config, so you should report it to them.